# Peel and stick flooring

Tags: tile

Wanting to install peel and stick flooring tiles directly onto concrete in my bedroom, cleaned and prepped of course. I’m gonna use vct adhesive between the tile and concrete to hold the tile better. Would this hold up long term?

Comment: Will depend on the quality/used of the tiles, but peel and stick is almost temporary flooring most times, five to ten years.

Comment: Over time, the gaps between the tiles tend to expand and collect dirt and grime.

Answer (score 1):

If there's any moisture in the concrete any time of year, fuggedaboutit.

As for using different adhesive on the belief that it will be better - probably not. It may in fact react poorly with the peel and stick adhesive and work **worse** as a result.

If the substrate and traffic are suitable for peel and stick, the adhesive it comes with works. I have P&S in two closets on particle-board subfloor. Been there more than 10 years. Those floors are reliably dry, though.

So, if your concrete floor is not in a basement, might work, but I would not mess with the adhesive. If your concrete floor is in a basement I'll respectfully doubt the odds of success. If you want to use VCT adhesive, buy Vinyl Commercial Tiles to use with it.

Comment: Being in closets probably help with them lasting a long time.  I doubt if the same long life is possible in a living space.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest that Peel and Stick should be looked at as a temporary measure.  If you want to go ahead, then my suggestion

1. Etch clean the floor (one of the products is called **Concrete & Paving Bare Concrete Etch & Clean**).  Be careful with the fumes
2. Spray it with a penetrating concrete barrier (one such product is called **Moisture Barrier** or **Damp Proofing**).  Some are silicon-based, others are resin.  Obviously, tar based ones won't work for you.
3. Then install the tiles.